# Can't install docopt module in a virtual env

Tags: linux, pip, centos, python-3.7, python-venv

I am trying to install docopt module in a virtual env, which is failing, but able to install urllib3 module.
I am creating virtual env as a unprivileged user

```
$ python3 -m venv yogi-venv
$ source yogi-venv/bin/activate
$ pip3 install urllib3
Collecting urllib3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/64/43575537846896abac0b15c3e5ac678d787a4021e906703f1766bfb8ea11/urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: urllib3
Successfully installed urllib3-1.26.6
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 21.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

$ pip3 install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/d7/f505e91e2cdea53cfcf51f4ac478a8cd64fb0bc1042629cedde20d9a6a9b/pip-21.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.6MB 15.2MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-21.2.2

$ pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        21.2.2
setuptools 39.0.1
urllib3    1.26.6

$ pip3 install docopt
Collecting docopt
  Using cached docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz (25 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/servicejenkins_build/yogi-venv/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-r1pocera/docopt_bf20fbd042814635ba33a7f102d490d3/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-r1pocera/docopt_bf20fbd042814635ba33a7f102d490d3/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-lk__1tg2
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-r1pocera/docopt_bf20fbd042814635ba33a7f102d490d3/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-lk__1tg2/docopt.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-lk__1tg2/docopt.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-lk__1tg2/docopt.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-lk__1tg2/docopt.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-lk__1tg2/docopt.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib2to3/Grammar3.7.0.final.0.pickle'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/55/8f8cab2afd404cf578136ef2cc5dfb50baa1761b68c9da1fb1e4eed343c9/docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz#sha256=49b3a825280bd66b3aa83585ef59c4a8c82f2c8a522dbe754a8bc8d08c85c491 (from https://pypi.org/simple/docopt/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached docopt-0.6.1.tar.gz (25 kB)
```

Any ideas where I am wrong?